# Confusion with string split method in python

Tags: python, string, split

Consider the following example

```
a= 'Apple'
b = a.split(',')
print(b)
```

Output is `['Apple']`.

I am not getting why is it returning a list even when there is no `','` character in `Apple`

There might be case when we use split method we are expecting more than one element in list but since we are splitting based on separator not present in string, there will be only one element, wouldn't it be better if this mistake is caught during this split method itself

Comment: What mistake? What if it is **not** a mistake to split on a missing delimiter? What if the delimiter is optional? You can more easily test for the resulting length.

Comment: And what did you want to happen instead? That an exception should be raised?

Comment: The advantage of this is that you always know you have a list afterwards, simplifying onward processing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i had thought there should be some exception but after seeing below answers understood the concept clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of `a.split(',')` when no commas are present in `a` is perfectly consistent with the way it behaves when there are a positive number of commas in `a`.

`a.split(',')` says to split string `a` into a list of substrings that are delimited by `','` in `a`; the delimiter is not preserved in the substrings.

If 1 comma is found you get 2 substrings in the list, if 2 commas are found you get 3 substrings in the list, and in general, if *n* commas are found you get *n+1* substrings in the list. So if 0 commas are found you get 1 substring in the list.

If you want 0 substrings in the list, then you'll need to supply a string with -1 commas in it. Good luck with that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The docstring of that method says:

> Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the delimiter string.

The delimiter is used to separate multiple parts of the string; having only one part is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way `split()` function works. If you do not want that behaviour, you can implement your `my_split()` function as follows:

```
def my_split(s, d=' '):
    return s.split(d) if d in s else s
```